# Jump to target host with bastion SSH key on Bastion/Jump host

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm working on a way to decentralise our SSH keys. The goal is to give each developer/admin/system manager a single SSH key.

This SSH key is added to the authorized_keys file on the bastion server. Now I have the command below that works perfectly when running as a terminal command:

```
ssh -t bastion@bastion.domain.tld ssh -i /home/bastion/.ssh/id_rsa target.domain.tld
```

Now I'm trying to convert this command into an `~/.ssh/config` entry. But after many attempts, none have worked.

I have tried using the block below, but with this the target server is using the admin's SSH keys which of course doesn't succeed.

```
Host *.domain.tld !bastion.domain.tld
    ProxyJump bastion@bastion.domain.tld
```

I've also tried using nc, but this is giving me the same result.

```
Host *.domain.tld !bastion.domain.tld
  IdentityFile /home/bastion/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand ssh bastion@bastion.domain.tld nc %h %p
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try first to change the working command into one using `-J`. Then you can try to map that into an ~/.ssh/config with ProxyJump.

Comment: Uh, I'm not entirely sure how making everyone use the same `/home/bastion/.ssh/id_rsa` constitutes _decentralising_ SSH keys?

Comment: Also look into using a CA to sign your keys, see e.g. [here](https://www.lorier.net/docs/ssh-ca.html). It will make the setup with one key for each developer etc. a lot easier.